# Vue: Img tags below v-for are not updated when the collection is filtered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have vue app in which i iterate over an array of objects using v-for. The iteration works fine and everything is outputtet correctly.

However, when i filter the list of objects only some of the sub elements are updated. Specifically my img-tags's src and srcsets are not updated.

Note that I use vue-lazysizes to load the images initially.

My code is as follows:

```
<label v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
    <div class="collection__item__image">
        <img ref="itemThumb" :alt="option.imageAlt" class="lazyload" v-bind:data-src="option.imageThumb" v-bind:srcset="'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='" v-bind:data-srcset="option.imageThumb">
    </div>
</label>
```

When the options collection is filtered, the elements are updated as well, including the data-src and data-srcset, but the src and srcset elements are not updated, meaning that they reflect some old data.

Do I need to do something to ensure that the src and srcset fields are updated as well?

Comment: It seems that it is caused by the lazy load component - It loads the src and srcset fields when the images are visible, but this is not bound to the model - I am unsure how to actually solve this problem. I have a lot of images so I don't want to limit the use of lazyload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that my problem was in the :key i used. I just used the index and that was not a good idea :). I have now changed to user a proper key (my options have an id that can be used) and after that it worked.

The code is now:

```
<label v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="option.id">
    <div class="collection__item__image">
        <img ref="itemThumb" :alt="option.imageAlt" class="lazyload" v-bind:data-src="option.imageThumb" v-bind:srcset="'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=='" v-bind:data-srcset="option.imageThumb">
    </div>
</label>
```